# What does rosawesome do?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It sounds like it must do something pretty awesome, yet I can't find any info on this mysterious executable inside ROS.

From inside rosbash;

```
function rosawesome {
    alias megamaid=rosrecord
    alias suck2blow=rosplay
    alias botherder=roscore
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45463/what-does-rosawesome-do?/) by [Jeremy Corbett](https://answers.ros.org/users/2912/jeremy-corbett/) on ROS Answers with karma: 397 on 2012-10-09

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SivamPillai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2018/sivampillai/) on 2012-10-09**:
Wow... I never knew such a command existed in ROS and definitely it sounds awesome :) I'd follow this question to know what it does!

**Comment by [McMurdo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1973/mcmurdo/) on 2014-07-09**:
I was just about to ask a question. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I will defer to Ken Conley, by way of ROSCon 2012: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KPSyW1zGarA&t=40s

---

Originally posted by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) with karma: 3248 on 2012-10-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 11

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

After I posted the comment I just checked the function you have typed in and from there it was clear enough of what rosawesome must be doing. From my knowledge it provides new alias names for the functions 'rosrecord', 'roscore' and 'rosplay'.

So, if you run **'rosawesome'** in the terminal and follow this with the instruction **'botherder'** for example, then it will actually run **'roscore'**.

Probably, you can use this function to personalize the ros commands by the names you prefer or it may be used in the future for possible addition of new features.

Anyways I enjoyed to get to know this new information.

Hope that Helps.

---

Originally posted by [SivamPillai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2018/sivampillai/) with karma: 612 on 2012-10-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-10-09**:
True, rosawesome adds a few aliases for commands. As far as I know, it's just an awesome relict from the early days of ros when people liked to name things differently. I hope someone from Willow can give us a little more information...

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rosawesome is there to remind you that Morgan Quigley is awesome.

*(as if any of us needed to be reminded)*

---

Originally posted by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) with karma: 5809 on 2012-10-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8